# Using regex_search to locate and output 6 specific time-stamps from an XML file in C++

Tags: c++, regex, xml

Over this weekend I've been attempting to familiarize myself with regex with the intention of implementing it into a C++ program in order to extract [6 specific time-stamps,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OhA7.png) and not only output them to the console window, but output them to a simple output text file. Below is what I have mustered up so far. However, what I have below only prints the first timestamp to the console window, and only prints the first timestamp to the output file as well, ignoring the other 5.  Could someone help me find where I've gone wrong? the regular expression works, after testing it out on http://regexr.com/

XML file: http://pastebin.com/5hMy9RzK

Screenshot of the console window in the present state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZPGJ.jpg

Screenshot of 6 time-stamps I am attempting to extract: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OhA7.png

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
ifstream infile;
ofstream outFile;
string fileinput;
int i = 0;
outFile.open("Outputdata.txt");
infile.open("Groupproject.xml"); // Opens the XML file containing the information that is to be read

regex time_regex("\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\w\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\.716Z");

smatch time_matches;




if (infile.fail())
{
    cout << "The file is not able to be located" << endl;
    system("Pause");
    exit(1);
}


while (!infile.eof()) {  //Until the end of the file is reached, obtain each line
    getline(infile, fileinput);

    if (regex_search(fileinput, time_matches, time_regex)) { // if regex_search is able to locate a line which has elements matching the regex expression "time_regex" output the located element

    cout << "Timestamp: " << time_matches[i] << endl;
    outFile << time_matches[i];
    i++;
}

}
infile.close();
outFile.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is here:

    `cout << "Timestamp: " << time_matches[i] << endl;
    outFile << time_matches[i];
    i++;`

Note that you are using `time_matches[i]` where `i` is initially `0` (zero) ...
... and it should always be zero...

but later you increment it:

   `i++;`

`time_matches[0]` is a copy of everything that matched your regex.

Also try rethinking parsing XML or HTML data with regular expressions, if you have XML parser available use that.

Comment: I am using regex because as a freshman CS major, I have very limited knowledge, and I am afraid implementing an XML parser is out of my realm of knowledge. However, I think Regex would work in this particular case, since the solution doesn't need to be portable, it just need to work in this one use-case, with this one particular XML file. So since apparently `time_matches[0]` is a copy of everything that matched my regex,  is there a way to output the 6 different time-stamps that are copied into `time_matches[0]` ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind `cout << "Timestamp: " << time_matches[0] << endl;` works when substituted with what I had before. I guess you you only need to iterate through an array of capture groups if there are multiple capture groups for a single line

Comment: I have tried to extend the code in an attempt to extract 1 specific line of power consumption data(Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/TQ5tyNZ.jpg) from the same XML file with the goal of eventually finding the average of all of the numbers in that specific line. However, when I try to extrapolate the solution that worked for the time-stamps to work in this particular instance, I am not able get my code to produce the result I want. Also, would there be a way to somehow find the average of those numbers easily? My code presently: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ce615b0402817e0bceb

Comment: You don't say what result you do get consider changing your regex from `3[8-9]\d\d\s+` to `3[8-9]\d\d\s*` to avoid requiring a space at the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry, I should of specified. The result I was getting was: http://imgur.com/WE8z5F8 Now, after changing the regex expression from `3[8-9]\d\d\s+` to `3[8-9]\d\d\s* `' I obtain: http://imgur.com/PJe9zwc . Which is better, but still isn't the full line of 25 numbers

Comment: Actually using `3[8-9]\d\d\s* ` isn't really better, since that regex expression includes 3 gratuitous lines that aren't part of the 25 I want to pick up, which is why 4 figures are outputted when using  `3[8-9]\d\d\s* `. Example of gratutious line picked up by `3[8-9]\d\d\s* `  : http://i.imgur.com/9qpbsdb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the wrong tool for the job, because XML is not a regular language (in the technical computer science sense of the term). Use an XML parser. If you use regular expressions, your program will be incorrect. It might work on 9999 out of 10000 input documents, but sooner or later it will fail. If someone malicious wants to find a weak point in your system, then of course it will fail a lot sooner.

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, I am a freshman in CS and unfortunately I don't think I will be able to implement an XML parser easily with the limited knowledge I possess. This is simply being used for a group project, where it only needs to function with a single XML file, so I think regex could work in this particular use case. However, your argument for using an XML parser certainly does have merit if the solution was intended to be more portable.